# Materialize calendar without box

Tags: html, materialize, embedding

I wish to be able to create a [Materialize date picker](http://materializecss.com/forms.html#date-picker) without having to click on the input-style box.  Does anyone know if this is possible or how to do so?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far or searched for other relating questions?

Comment: @JohannesPiontkowitz I have had a brief look for questions like mine but the ones I found are either inconclusive or unanswered.

Comment: @JohannesPiontkowitz I would have no idea where to start with this at all.

Comment: You need to find out how to trigger the datepicker so that it shows. And you might need an invisible input to store the selected date in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With JavaScript open the date picker window by calling the `click` method on the input field:

```
var datepickers = $('.datepicker').pickadate();
datepickers[0].click();
```

The [next version of materialize](http://next.materializecss.com/pickers.html) adds an `open` method for which you use as follows:

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.datepicker');
var datepickers = M.Datepicker.init(inputs);
datepickers[0].open();
```